# Rxjs catchError not working when subscribe after pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I have created an observable to consume an API

Observable:-

```
    return this.http.post('/api/ApplicationUser/Login', loginDetails, httpOptions).pipe(
      map((result: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', result.jwtToken);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', result.refreshToken.value)
        localStorage.setItem('UserName', result.userName);
        return result;
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        //this.userLogout()
        console.log('refresh error')
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

Above code is working fine by results or throwing errors according to my situations when Iam activating with below code:-

```
    this.loginService.getNewRefreshToken().subscribe(
      (res => { console.log(res) }),
      (err => { 
        this.loginService.userLogout()
        console.log(err)
      }),
      () => { console.log('subscription completed')},
    );
```

But my problem is when Iam activating it with below code its catchError not working but results are fine.
Why catchError is not working in below case?

```
    return this.loginService.getNewRefreshToken().pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    ).subscribe(
      (res => {
      console.log(res)
    }),
      (err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
      )
```

Comment: Which of the `catchError ` statement is not firing?

Comment: `catchError` inside `if (!this.tokenRefreshing) {}` this block

Comment: your code seems fine

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine on StackBlitz. The only issue I see here is when you use `map` in `loginService.getNewRefreshToken`, you're not returning anything, so your data will come as `undefined`. You also should be using [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) instead of `map` since you just want to perform side-effects and not actually manipulate the data. The `catchError` issue must have something to do with interceptor as you mentioned in one of the comments in the answers. On another note, why do you want to catch the error again in your component anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getNewRefreshToken` function eats the exception hence it does not get propagated to upstream listeners.

Try [throwError](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError)

```
 getNewRefreshToken(): Observable<any> {
   var loginDetails: LoginDetails = {
   email: localStorage.getItem('UserName'),
   grantType: 'refreshToken',
   password: '',
   refreshToken: localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')
  }

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  }),
 };

return this.http.post('/api/ApplicationUser/Login', loginDetails, httpOptions).pipe(
  map((result: LoginResponse) => {
    localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', result.jwtToken);
    localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', result.refreshToken.value)
    localStorage.setItem('UserName', result.userName);
    return result;
  }),
  catchError((err: any) => {
    this.userLogout()
    console.log('refresh error')
    return throwError(err);  //<-- insert this 
  })
);
}
```

[Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mjdnv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts) See the results in console.

Comment: I tried it but even code is not entering in catchError block itself

Comment: No
for checking that block exec i added that.
but its not working

Comment: If `refresh error` is not printed, it means your POST call is returning proper response. Check if your webapi indeed returns the expected return code.

Comment: I can see that post request as 401

Comment: Try calling the post request method with `catchError` on click of button and see if the `catchError` block is working as expect. I suspect there is something fishy here.

Comment: `refreshToken() {
    this.loginService.getNewRefreshToken().pipe(
      map(res => {
        console.log(res)
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
`

tried that and with a button click and map is hitting fine but incase of error its not going to catchError, also getting 401 in console

Comment: I think some problem in intecpetor code pipe of `next.handle`.
i have removed them and its hitting catchError successfully

Comment: I have updated question with some more details

please have a look

Comment: @AmeerPappay - Please edit your question and post the steps that you did to solve the problem. It is a rude practice to ask someone to delete their answer if they have spent time answering your question and the answer is correct.