# How Rxjs filter postponds http calls till the criteria matches in below code?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have block of code which returns an `next` function of angular interceptor iff the value of a `tokenSubject` behaviour subject is not null.

```
if (!this.tokenRefreshing) {
  this.tokenRefreshing = true;
  this.tokenSubject.next(null);
  return this.loginService.getNewRefreshToken().pipe(
    switchMap((tokenResponse: any) => {
      if (tokenResponse) {
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', tokenResponse.jwtToken);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', tokenResponse.refreshToken.value)
        localStorage.setItem('UserName', tokenResponse.userName);
        this.tokenSubject.next(tokenResponse);
        console.log('token refreshed');
        return next.handle(this.attachAuthToken(request));
      }
      else return <any>this.loginService.userLogout();
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      this.loginService.userLogout();
      return this.handleError(err);
    }),
    finalize(() => {
      this.tokenRefreshing = false;
    })
  )
}
else {
  return this.tokenSubject.pipe(
    filter(token => token != null),
    take(1),
    switchMap(token => {
      return next.handle(this.attachAuthToken(request))
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.tokenRefreshing = false;
      return this.loginService.userLogout();
    })
  )
}
```

I cant understand how this works if multiple http calls hits there and how it postpones and executes all in order after behaviour subject has a token value in it. can anyone help me to understand this?

Comment: where are the other codes before this code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all just make it clear that this the error handling logic in this.handle401Error method (https://angular-academy.com/angular-jwt/)

if you are executing this means your token is invalidated, and you need to get a refresh token. So lets say you have 5 https calls hitting this block when the token is no longer valid. The first http call hits it, it change

```
this.tokenRefreshing = true;
```

and immediately emit tokenSubject as null by

```
  this.tokenSubject.next(null);
```

then it request the new token and once it got that it sets the token in header and carry pass on to let the original request through

```
next.handle(this.attachAuthToken(request));
```

so that's how the first http completes.

But now you have another http kicks in while you are refreshing the token (1st http on going and requesting refresh token).

this 2nd http call will run `else` block because `this.tokenRefreshing` is true, so it looks in the tokenSubject see if there's any value, and at this moment it doesn't. so the call will just hang/pause there but will not be canceled, as you are filter out `token===null`

```
filter(token => token != null),
```

so when 1st http is completed fetching refreshtoken it does this

```
this.tokenSubject.next(tokenResponse);
```

that will trigger the 2nd http call to resume the subsequent stream items

```
   take(1),
    switchMap(token => {
      return next.handle(this.attachAuthToken(request))
    }),
    catchError((error) => {
      this.tokenRefreshing = false;
      return this.loginService.userLogout();
    })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok

I have got that,but,
 `so the call will just hang/pause there but will not be canceled`

whihc operator makes this possible? filter?

Comment: Yes. Filter will only allow stream to carry on if token not null, then pass to take(1) which completes the stream

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004026/rxjs-pipe-not-catching-errors/58011886?noredirect=1#comment102450401_58011886

Can u please have a look into this question alos?

Comment: Ok maybe later today or tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

As you mention you have an interceptor. Interceptors in general are executed in order. An intercept method returned an observable (`Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`). You now return an async subject pipe-mapped to this obvservable, which completes after you received a token. Angular waits for this completion.